# How to properly scroll inline element inside parent

Tags: html, css

I have a grid element inside parent container.
The grid should be 100% width of a parent container when it's big enough.
A scroll bar should appear when parent container is not big enough.

With `display: inline-grid` or any other inline object scroller appears but grid doesn't stretch to parent width when it's bigger.

With `display: grid` it works but scrolling is weird because red background doesn't cover all of grid columns.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-x: auto;">
        <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; background-color: red">
            <div style="white-space: nowrap;">Column start</div>
            <div style="white-space: nowrap;">Column start</div>
            <div style="white-space: nowrap;">Column start</div>
        </div>
<!--        <div style="white-space: nowrap; background-color: red; display: inline-block">-->
<!--            Hello world very long text blah blah-->
<!--        </div>-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: inline-grid + min-width:100%

Comment: Cannot post it as an answer, you have an [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/u0o7yp4e/)

Comment: This reminds me on how i hate CSS